# Why changes made with processor expert do not apply to my code?

Tags: embedded, codewarrior

I am facing a problem with Processor Expert in CodeWarrior.
I can't make changes made in peripheral apply to the generated code.
For example, in a code that uses a timer, if I disable the timer, regenerate the code, compile and load the code, it keeps working.

On the other hand, if I start a project from scratch, the same code does not work until I enable the peripherals (in this example, the timer).

So it looks like the first code generation works fine, but then any change made to the same peripheral has no effect.

I tried searching for a clue, and took a look at the Processor Expert user guide, with no luck so far. I appreciate any idea about what I could be doing wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem a little while after posting this answer. I had started the project with the option *Processor expert* enabled. I started a new project, enabling *Device initialization* instead. Everithing works as expected now, whit the modifications done in Target CPU windows applying to mcuinit.c after generating the code.
[This user guide](http://cache.freescale.com/files/soft_dev_tools/doc/support_info/CWMCU10_DeviceInitHelp.pdf) helped me undestand the difference between **Device Initialization** and **Processor Expert**.